# WSO2 API Manager + Set Prioritization

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

How can we implement Message mediation level prioritization in WSO2 API manager. Since WSO2 ESB is embedded in API manager, Can i enable this capability in API manager itself. I understand that it is available in seperate WSO2 ESB. I do not want to have seperate EB layer for it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is recommended to seperate out API Management and Mediation layer, you can still run ESB (mediation)activities within the API Manager. If you are familiar with sequences in ESB the same sequences and API's are used to define the API's that are exposed in the API Manager. You can directly access the source of the API's that are created from the management console of the API Manager (http://{IP}:{PORT}/carbon). Here you will find a Service Bus section on the left hand navigation section under which there is a 'sourceview'. From there you can access the API definitions and add the priority mediator[1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Prioritizing+Messages